# messed up /boot ownership

Tags: boot, centos, chown

I messed up /boot directory ownership (CentOS8) and i'm not sure to whom to restore it to. Backstory, the product from work that I am working on has it's own user and group to run its own services. Now that the entire /boot directory is under that user/group and I'm pretty certain that user should NOT own /boot. I'm not sure whom to restore it back to - myself or root?

Inside the boot there is grub2, efi and loader - 100% certain that the product's user/group should not own these.

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/boot and its descendants should be owned by UID **0** that means **root:root**.

```
sudo chown -R root:root /boot
```